# @PostConstruct method called twice for the same request

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, postconstruct

I'm using JSF 2.0 with GlassFish 3.0.

I have the following Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OverviewController{

    private List<Event> eventList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("=> OverviewController - init() - enter");

        System.out.println("=< OverviewController - init() - exit");
    }
}
```

From the the *overview.xhtml* file I'm calling different attributes or methods from my OverviewController.

```
<ui:repeat var="event" value="#{overviewController.eventList}">
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

Everything works just fine but the problem is on the Log File:

```
INFO: Enter : RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: Exit : RESTORE_VIEW 1

INFO: Enter : RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: => OverviewController - init() - enter
INFO: => Overview Controller - updateSelectedTab() - enter
INFO: =< Overview Controller - updateSelectedTab() - exit
INFO: =< OverviewController - init() - exit
INFO: => OverviewController - init() - enter
INFO: => Overview Controller - updateSelectedTab() - enter
INFO: =< Overview Controller - updateSelectedTab() - exit
INFO: =< OverviewController - init() - exit
INFO: Exit : RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

As you can see, The init() method is called twice in the same request for no reason what so ever. From what I know, any method annotated with *PostConstruct* is called once every request. Am I wrong?

**EDIT:**
No AJAX is used on the page.
I checked the number of requests with firebug. There are tree requests made:

- 1.One for the javax.faces.resource *(GET)*
- 2.One for the css file *(GET)*
- 3.One for overview.xhtml *(GET)*

Comment: Are you mean ClassFish or GlassFish?

Comment: Are you performing any Ajax calls?  Use FireBug or similar add on to find out how many requests the browser is actually making.

Comment: On this page there are some tips for debugging JSF lifecycles. Check it out, maybe it is something there that can help you http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks! Sadly I couldn't find there anything which could explain my problem. It seems that all the methods annotated with @PostConstruct are called twice in Invoke Application or RenderResponse

Comment: What if you name the `init()` method something else, such as `myInit()`? init() method was used before to initialize servlets (AFAIK), could it be that Glassfish is running init() in one state of the life cycle and @PostConstruct in another? Is this related? http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2011/07/servlet-init-method-vs-postconstruct.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That can happen if you have multiple frameworks managing the same bean class. E.g. JSF *and* CDI, or JSF *and* Spring, or CDI *and* Spring, etc. Doublecheck your configuration and annotations on the bean.

That can also happen if you're using CDI and are using multiple `@Named` annotations throughout the class. For example, a `@Named` straight on the class to register it as a managed bean and another one on a `@Produces` getter method. You'd need to ask yourself whether that is *really* necessary. You could also just use `#{bean.someObject}` instead of `#{someObject}`.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ...
    }

    @Named
    @Produces
    public SomeObject getSomeObject() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

That can also happen if your managed bean extends some abstract class which has in turn also a `@PostConstruct` on the method. You should remove the annotation from it. Alternatively, you should make the init method abstract and *not* have `@PostConstruct` on the implementing bean:

```
public abstract class BaseBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        init();
    }

    public abstract void init();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't have multiple frameworks but this helped me to understand what the problem was. All my ManagedBeans extend a `BaseController`. This BaseController has a `@PostConstruct init()` method which I thought it would be override by the other ManagedBeans' `PostConstruct init()`. It seems though that both `init()` are called. It all makes sense now.. Thank you!

Comment: You should not have `@PostConstruct` in the `BaseController` class. Remove it.

Comment: @BalusC: I have a small side question. Regarding using JSF and CDI on the same bean, if I use `@Inject` to inject a CDI bean into a `@ManagedBean`, will the `@PostConstruct` method be called twice? I'm not quite sure how to apply multiple framework on the same bean. I thought that the framework was decided by annotated the bean with `@ManagedBean`, `@Named`, etc.

Comment: @BalusC I have the same problem. I have defined `@PostConstruct` method inside `@Controller` class. Is there any problem in it? Actually, I want to start my scheduler on app deployment. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the both `init()` method and `@PostConstruct` methods are firing and causing this behavior. Try changing the name of the `init()` method and/or putting it `private`. I think that this may be related to your problems:

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2011/07/servlet-init-method-vs-postconstruct.html

I also found a good post about debugging JSF life cycles here: 
[Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)

Comment: This makes no sense. A JSF managed bean is not a `HttpServlet` implementation.

Comment: I meant that depending on configuration it may cause the system to get confused and fire on both methods. Maybe it was a long shot though. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: I tried removing the annotation but then the init() would be ignored. As BalusC said it seems that there is no init() method in a managed bean.

Comment: @Peder: JSF has absolutely no special treatment for methods called `init()`. You're confusing with `HttpServlet#init()`. Please re-read the javahowto article which you linked yourself.