# Same @PostConstruct calling twice, data not surviving

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I'm learning JSF/Primefaces. whenever user click on a link it should forward to the edit page with the information, but it's empty.

I tried to debug, following flow happens:

- user click the link of the element that wants to edit
- QuoteStatusList.init() is called
- QuoteStatusForm.init() is called
- QuoteStatusForm.edit is called
- QuotestatusForm.quoteStatus bean is filled with the information
- return "edit"
- foward to quoteStatusForm.xhtml
- and QuoteStatusForm.init() is called again, all datas filled are lost

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077966/postconstruct-method-called-twice-for-the-same-request) but I'm now only using jsf annotation to manage view beans

QuoteStatusList.java

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScope    
public class QuoteStatusList extends BasePage implements Serializable {
        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            log.debug("initing...");
        }
    ...
    }
```

QuoteStatusForm.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScope
    public class QuoteStatusForm extends BasePage implements Serializable {
    @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            log.debug("initing...");
        }

    public String edit() {
            log.debug("editing..");
             if (idQuoteStatus != null && idQuoteStatus != 0) {
                quoteStatus = quoteStatusManager.get(idQuoteStatus);
            } else {
                quoteStatus = new QuoteStatus();
            }  
            return "edit";
        }

    }
```

BasePage.java

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BasePage {
    //nothing is injected
//no other @postConstruct function
}
```

QuoteStatusList.xhtml

```
<h:commandLink action="#{quoteStatusForm.edit}" value="#{quoteStatus.idQuoteStatus}">
                        <f:param name="idQuoteStatus" value="#{quoteStatus.idQuoteStatus}"/>
                    </h:commandLink>
```

faces-config.xml

```
 <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/quoteStatusList.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>edit</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/quoteStatusForm.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/quoteStatusForm.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>edit</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/quoteStatusForm.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

Comment: What's `quoteStatus` from `value="#{quoteStatus.idQuoteStatus}"` supposed to be?

Comment: QuoteStatus a plain java bean, String name, String description. idQuoteStatus = an Integer

Comment: Does that actually work? If it's not a `@ManagedBean` or scoped within one of the 4 (or 5) web application scopes, it would serve no purpose there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you're experiencing is appropriate behaviour** for `@RequestScoped` and `@ViewScoped` beans.

1. `@RequestScoped` - Beans of this scope will not survive a redirect/forward to another page. That means that if you're on a page backed by a bean of this scope, whenever you issue a new HTTP request (either ajax, a full-on page refresh, or a redirect), the instance of that bean you're working on is **destroyed**, voided, ceases to exist. Along with all its member variables
2. `@ViewScoped` - Beans of this scope will also not survive a full redirect/forward. They will however survive page refreshes and ajax. What this means is that, as long as you stay on the same page (backed by a `@ViewScoped` bean), don't return any navigation case, you're guaranteed to be working with the same instance of the bean.

---

**How are these beans supposed to communicate then?** If leaving one page means that you lose everything the backing bean contains, what your options (you should be asking)? Well, there are a number of ways that JSF beans can communicate. Read through [the gospel on inter-bean communication](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

---

**So what's happening in your case**

1. `QuoteStatusList` list is destroyed when you navigate away from the page that it backs. This also means that when you come back, you're dealing with a brand new instance of that bean (and that's why `init` is called twice)
2. `QuoteStatusForm` was destroyed because you returned `edit` from that bean, causing the instance you're working with to be destroyed and recreated on page load

---

**What to do:**

To avoid destroying `QuoteStatusForm`, you can just return `null` from `edit`

Comment: I tried t o return null from edit(), if I do that the page will alwasy stays in the quoteStatusList.xhtml page. because it calls the edit() function first, gather the information, then redirect to quoteStatusform.xhtml.

Comment: That's not what your config says @Kossel. You're returning `edit`, just to return to the same page you were on. Why?

Comment: Also, how are you getting access to `quoteStatusManager` from within the `edit` method @Kossel. You're not instantiating it by yourself are you?

Comment: exactly, I should return void there. but for somehow, if I return null or void, the page stuck at the listing page, because no rule tells the application to display the form page. that's why I put "return edit"

Comment: I think you misunderstand me, I'm referring to the `edit` outcome from `quoteStatusForm`. Return null in that `edit` method @Kossel

Comment: I understood you :S if I return null in the edit(), the page will stay at the listing page...  because it's not forwarding to the detail form page.. (quoteStatusForm.xhtml)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62383/discussion-between-kossel-and-kolossus).