# @PostConstrution called multiple times

Tags: spring

I have created a class which implements two interfaces.

I have used a init method with @postconstruction annotation

I am observing that though bean is initialised only during start up, init method is called multiple times.

Comment: are you using another framework like JSF or CDI or similar? or just spring?

Comment: It's an app based on spring framework,

Comment: check this post [@PostConstruct method called twice for the same request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077966/postconstruct-method-called-twice-for-the-same-request). You should post your class too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @PostConstruct method will be called every time the bean is instantiated. This means either every time you do a "new", or, if you've registered your class with a @Service, @Repository, or any other anotation of sorts that registers the class as a spring bean, the first time you @Autowired it.

Watch out for instantations of the class aside from those if you are using another framework annotations like @ManagedBean in JSF, which could be instantiating your class without you realising it.

Comment: We are using @autowiring annotation